Summation I came up with inspired by Putnam A5 2023
Define $f(k)$ to equal the number of ones in the base three representation of $k$ (For example, $f(43)=3$ since $43=1121_{3}$). Evaluate $$\sum_{\substack{1\leq k \leq 1012 \\a_{1}+a_{2}+...+a_{k}=2024  \\ a_{1}, a_{2},...,a_{k}\geq 0}}\frac{\left(-2\right)^{f\left(k\right)}}{a_{1}!\cdot a_{2}!\cdot...\cdot a_{k}!}.$$ My solution to solve this involves utilizing the generating function of $(-2)^{k}f(k)$ and applying the operator $x\frac{d}{dx}$ repeatedly, although a user on AOPS used a more traditional approach by applying a linear operator to the function and using recurrence relations. I would like to see other ways to evaluate this sum, as its clean answer suggests other combinatorial or algebra methods are possible to use.
P.S: the sum is presented in this unconventional form because I initially wanted to challenge this sum to some friends.

Clarification requested: $~1121_3~$ does not have any zeroes, so how can $~f(43) = 3 ~? $

"zero" was meant to be ones, my mistake, was a typo

The answer is $3^{1011\cdot 1012}$. For a nonnegative integer k, we claim that $$\sum_{\substack{a_{1}+a_{2}+...+a_{k}=2024  \\ a_{1}, a_{2},...,a_{k}\geq 0}}\frac{2024!}{a_{1}!\cdot a_{2}!\cdot...\cdot a_{k}!}=k^{2024}$$ with the convention that the empty sum equals 0 in the case where $k=0$. To show this, count the number of unordered multisets with $k$ elements from the set $\{1,2,...,k\}$ of size 2024. One one hand, for each of the 2024 elements, we have a possibility to choose $k$ elements across all 2024 positions of the set. On the other hand, suppose the number of times each integer $1\leq i\leq k$ is $a_{i}$: it is obvious that the sum of all $a_{i}$ must be 2024 since that is the total number of elements in the set. We can freely permute the 2024 elements and divide by $a_{i}!$ for each $i$ since permuting the same number among each other yields the same permutation. So now our sum is $$\frac{1}{2024!}\sum_{k=1}^{3^{1012-1}}\left(-2\right)^{f\left(k\right)}k^{2024}.$$ Define $p\left(x\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{3^{1012}-1}\left(-2\right)^{f\left(k\right)}x^{k}$: equivalently, we have that $$p\left(x\right)=\prod_{n=0}^{1011}\left(1-2x^{3^{n}}+x^{2\cdot3^{n}}\right)=\left(x-1\right)^{2024}\prod_{n=0}^{1011}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{3^{n}-1}x^{k}\right)^{2}.$$ This is true because $\prod_{n=0}^{1011}\left(1+x^{3^{n}}+x^{2\cdot3^{n}}\right)$ is the generating function for all base three numbers less than $3^{1012}$:we know that every number has a unique representation in any nontrivial base, and the coefficient -2 is to account for the $(-2)^{f(k)}$ term. Define the operator $T\left(f\left(x\right)\right)=x\frac{d}{dx}f\left(x\right)$, and write $T^{a}$ as $a$ repeated applications of $T$: observe that $T^{a}\left(p\left(x\right)\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{3^{1012}-1}\left(-2\right)^{f\left(k\right)}k^{a}x^{k}$. We claim that for all $j>1$, $$T^{j}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}r\left(j,k\right)x^{k}\frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}}f\left(x\right)+x^{j}\frac{d^{j}}{dx^{j}}f\left(x\right)$$ where $r$ is some arbitrary function. The hypothesis is true for $j=2$, since $T^{2}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)=xf'\left(x\right)+x^{2}f''\left(x\right)$. If we proceed inductively, for some arbitrary $j$, we have $$T^{j+1}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)$$ $$=x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}r\left(j,k\right)x^{k}\frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}}f\left(x\right)+x^{j}\frac{d^{j}}{dx^{j}}f\left(x\right)\right)$$ $$=\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}r\left(j,k\right)\left(kx^{k}\frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}}f\left(x\right)+x^{k+1}\frac{d^{k+1}}{dx^{k+1}}f\left(x\right)\right)+jx^{j}\frac{d^{j}}{dx^{j}}f\left(x\right)+x^{j+1}\frac{d^{j+1}}{d^{j+1}}f\left(k\right)$$ $$=\sum_{k=1}^{j}s\left(j,k\right)x^{k}\frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}}+x^{j+1}\frac{d^{j+1}}{d^{j+1}}f\left(k\right)$$ where $s$ is again an arbitrary function, and we move every term of the $j$th derivative or lower inside the sum, which completes the induction. Since $$\sum_{k=0}^{3^{1012}-1}\left(-2\right)^{f\left(k\right)}k^{2024}=T^{2024}\left(p\left(x\right)\right)\biggr\rvert_{x=1}$$ we have that $p$ has a zero at $x=1$ of multiplicity $2024$: differentiation will reduce the multiplicity by 1 on each application, which means that the 2023rd derivatives of $p$ and lower will all zero out at $x=1$. Therefore $$\sum_{k=0}^{3^{1012}-1}\left(-2\right)^{f\left(k\right)}k^{2024}=T^{2024}\left(p\left(x\right)\right)\biggr\rvert_{x=1}=\frac{d^{2024}}{dx^{2024}}p\left(x\right)\biggr\rvert_{x=1}.$$ To compute this derivative, we can construct the same vanishing argument with Leibniz's rule by viewing $p(x)$ as the product of $\left(x-1\right)^{2024}$ and $\prod_{n=0}^{1011}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{3^{n}-1}x^{k}\right)^{2}$: per Leibniz's rule, $$\frac{d^{2024}}{dx^{2024}}\left(f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{2024}\binom{2024}{n}\left(\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}f\left(x\right)\right)\left(\frac{d^{2024-n}}{dx^{2024-n}}g\left(x\right)\right).$$ But the 2023 derivative of $(x-1)^{2024}$ and below vanishes to 0 at $x=1$, and the 2024th derivative of the function at $x=1$ is $2024!$. Hence $$\frac{d^{2024}}{dx^{2024}}p\left(x\right)\biggr\rvert_{x=1}=2024!\prod_{n=0}^{1011}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{3^{n}-1}x^{k}\right)^{2}\biggr\rvert_{x=1}$$
$$=2024!\prod_{n=0}^{1011}\left(3^{n}\right)^{2}=2024!\prod_{n=0}^{1011}3^{2n}$$
$$=2024!\cdot3^{\sum_{n=0}^{1011}2n}$$ $$=2024!\cdot3^{2\cdot\frac{1011\cdot1012}{2}}=2024!\cdot3^{1011\cdot1012}$$ Since the original sum is $\frac{1}{2024!}\sum_{k=1}^{1012}\left(-2\right)^{f\left(k\right)}k^{2024}$, we obtain that the answer is $3^{1011\cdot 1012}$.

Nice answer and funny problem
